# Creating layers named after slices

Tags: fireworks

I have an issue that may well not be possible to solve 'out of the box'. I'm running fireworks 8 and would like to to be able to run the:

`Commands->Document->Split to layers`

and have the resulting layers created using the name of the slice that it created the layer for. So for example, if I have 3 slices in my png, called 'Head', Shoulder' and 'Arm', I'd like that command to create the layer name that corresponds to the slice name. As it currently stands, when running this command, the default layer names created are sequentially named 'Layer 1', 'Layer 2', 'Layer 3' etc etc.

The reason for this requirement is due to the fact that I then wish to use the `Export` command to save the individual Layers out to named png files that use the 'Slice names ('Head.png' etc), rather than the default Layer names. Now I know I can manually rename the layers to match the Slices, and Export to a folder as required. However, in my real life scenario, I have over 50 Slices per document that require this treatment and I have 100's of documents at a time to 'batch' process. So my idea was that I would be able to run a command (or create some sort of macro) that would allow me to create the layers with the same name as the slice that they contained.

This would make my life SOO much simpler as I could then totally automate the process based on a set of source images located within a folder structure, rather than opening each file, running the above command, renaming each layer manually (error prone of course) and then running the Export function.

Can anyone offer advice on finding a solution to this?? I hope I'm not the only one to have come across this requirement.

Comment: hey -any pointers on making this more on-topic for the target audience (I notice a few off-topic flags). I had planned to escalate to a bounty question if there were no answers in a few days, but obviously, the off-topic threat could scupper that. thanks

Comment: not being funny here, could anyone marking as 'offtopic' 'please' return and leave feeback as to why. I want to improve the quality of Q&A on SO but can only do so if I appreciate my crime and can repent accordingly. So, plea bargain - no hard feelings if you return and let me know why :) - you know you want to you!!

Comment: karthikr -lol, loved the extra poke with a -1 :)

Comment: How is this programming related?  It appears to be a question about using software not specifically targeted at programmers.

Comment: hey will, it was directly related to programming, the jsf related answer was my fix and was tagged as such. cheers

Comment: @Will Hi. There doesn't appear to be a tag for it (though there is one for the related [tag:jsfl]), but the question was to do with the [Fireworks Javascript API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/fireworks/cs/using/WSE1FCFAB6-8C6A-4164-8392-EFF705BBC652.html#WS4c25cfbb1410b0021e63e3d1152b00d8df-7ff3).

Comment: hey david, i even extended the fix further and applied the export option for png32, as well as using the fw.browseForFolderURL() call to grab a folder to save into. works like a treat now, single action, programatic fix as requested :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a line to the Split to Layers command [here](http://pastie.org/7115515). If you save that as `Distribute to Named Layers.jsf` in the same folder as the original command (in CS5.5 I found it in *Configuration/Commands/Document*), I think that should do what you need.

That said, jsf is fairly unpredictable in my experience (for example, that command seems to miss the default name of things like Rectangles until they've been renamed), so I'm not certain if it will work 100% of the time. Also, the script skips over the *Web Layer* which contains slices in 5.5 - I can't remember if the set up is different in 8. Hopefully that gets you some of the way there though.

Comment: david - without sounding like a fawning puppy -thank you so much for your response. I was honestly at a loss as to why I was getting so many non communicative votes to close... i thought this was a very relevant question as your answer has proven. I'll try your suggestion. thanks again and +1

Comment: No worries. Maybe swap the [graphics] tag for [jsfl]. Technically it's [jsf], but it's the same language, and [jsf] doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: ahhh -gotcha- tag change in op now

Comment: By the way, the new line is near the bottom, just after `// rename target layer if element has a name`. If the script *is* different in 8, you may still be able to just copy that line in to the equivalent place.

Comment: dang -not expecting tech support, but it came up with 'Could not run the Script.' 'An Error occurred'. so close too!! ahh -saw you above comment after this will try that simple change

Comment: yup, that simple change worked perfectly - you've just saved me potentially days of head scratching -thank you soo soo much. wish I could award you dbl ;)

Comment: Great, glad I could help before it got too flagged! Like I say, jsf can be a bit buggy so I hope it doesn't break weirdly, but here's the reference I was using in case it comes in handy: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/fireworks/cs/extend/index.html

Comment: hey david, i know i'm pushing it now. is there an addition to that macro to change the 'Optimize' settings to png32, and then 'select' the 'Web Layer'.?? I'm scottish, we're a bit cheeky like that :) btw -reviewing the fireworks link above too

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head I'm afraid (I've just been going off that reference). There are  "currentLayerNum" and "exportOptions" properties [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/fireworks/cs/extend/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d1183c94856c-7fff.html) which look promising though.

Answer (score 1):

FYI - here's what the final `programatic` fix amounted to (with thanks to david mear)

```
// This command will take multiple objects and move them to indivdual layers
// and then prompt for a folder location to save the layers as named-layer.png
// files. This is ultra useful if you want to save slices out to individual
// files and wish to have total control over the resulting file names

var curDoc = fw.getDocumentDOM();
// Save the current frame in the document
var curFrameNum = curDoc.currentFrameNum;

// get the total layers minus the web layer
var numLayers = curDoc.layers.length - 1;  // skip the web layer.

var curLayerNum;

// default to d:\ for now
var locFolder = fw.browseForFolderURL("select a folder", "file:///d|/");

// 23/3/2013 add dialog box for file
if (locFolder !== null) {
    // loop through the current number of layers
    for (curLayerNum = numLayers - 1; curLayerNum >= 0; curLayerNum--) {
        // get the current layer
        var curLayer = curDoc.layers[curLayerNum];

        // get the elements on the current layer
        var elements = curLayer.frames[curFrameNum].elements;
        //if layer is locked cannot distribute so continue to next layer.
        if (curLayer.frames[curFrameNum].locked == true)
            continue;
        // get the number of elements
        var numElements = elements.length - 1;
        var i;

        // loop through the number of elements
        for (i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
            // get the current layer number
            if (i == 0) curDoc.currentLayerNum = curLayerNum;
            // add layers for the number of elements
            curDoc.addNewLayer(null, false);
        }
        // again loop through the number of elements
        for (i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
            // set the current layer
            curLayer = curDoc.layers[curLayerNum];
            // get the elements on the current layer
            elements = curLayer.frames[curFrameNum].elements;
            // select none
            curDoc.selectNone();
            // create a new array that will hold the selection
            var sel = new Array();
            // populate the array
            sel[0] = elements[elements.length - 2];

            // EDIT - 25/3/2013 rename target layer if element has a name
            curDoc.setLayerName(curLayerNum + i + 1, sel[0].name || "");

            // select all of the elements of the array in Fireworks
            fw.selection = sel;
            // move the selection to its new layer
            curDoc.moveSelectionToLayer(curLayerNum + i + 1, false, "none", -1);
        }
    }

    // EDIT - 25/3/2013 set to png32 export option
    set_export_as_png_32(curDoc);
    fw.exportLayers(curDoc, locFolder);
}


function set_export_as_png_32(targetDoc) {
    targetDoc.setExportOptions(
        {
            animAutoCrop: true,
            animAutoDifference: true,
            applyScale: false,
            colorMode: "32 bit",
            crop: false,
            cropBottom: 0,
            cropLeft: 0,
            cropRight: 0,
            cropTop: 0,
            ditherMode: "none",
            ditherPercent: 100,
            exportFormat: "PNG",
            frameInfo: [],
            interlacedGIF: false,
            jpegQuality: 80,
            jpegSelPreserveButtons: false,
            jpegSelPreserveText: true,
            jpegSelQuality: 90,
            jpegSelQualityEnabled: false,
            jpegSmoothness: 0,
            jpegSubsampling: 0,
            localAdaptive: true,
            lossyGifAmount: 0,
            macCreator: "",
            macFileType: "",
            name: "PNG32",
            numCustomEntries: 0,
            numEntriesRequested: 0,
            numGridEntries: 6,
            optimized: true,
            paletteEntries: null,
            paletteInfo: null,
            paletteMode: "adaptive",
            paletteTransparency: "none",
            percentScale: 100,
            progressiveJPEG: false,
            savedAnimationRepeat: 0,
            sorting: "none",
            useScale: true,
            webSnapAdaptive: false,
            webSnapTolerance: 14,
            xSize: 0,
            ySize: 0
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I'd completely missed the `setExportOptions` method. I'm still not quite sure what the correct tag would be for jsf though. [tag:jsf] appears to be unrelated, so maybe just [tag:javascript],  or even a new "fireworksjs" tag. Glad it got sorted out in any case.

Comment: david, on reflection, yes `jsf` was incorrect. i added a `fireworksjs` tag of which this question may ever only be the sole occupant :) cheers again